# Offset all Canvas Lines

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, offset

I have the following canvas code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

var x = "black",
    y = 2;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('can');

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {

        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);
}

function color(obj) {
    switch (obj.id) {

        case "blue":
            x = "blue";
            break;
        case "red":
            x = "red";
            break;

        case "black":
            x = "black";
            break;
        case "white":
            x = "white";
            break;
    }
    if (x == "white") y = 14;
    else y = 2;

}

function draw() {


    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function erase() {
    var m = confirm("Want to clear");
    if (m) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function save() {
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
}

function findxy(res, e) {
    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            draw();
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

However because of CSS having margin/padding/width/height on my parent elements, the canvas is returning an offset to the left and bottom, is there any way to forcefully apply a negative offset back to the mouse location or is it possible to just get the MOUSE location instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.getBoundingClientRect` which accounts for CSS styling & repositioning:

```
var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var BBoffsetX=BB.left;
var BBoffsetY=BB.top;
var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-BBoffsetX);
var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-BBoffsetY);
```

Comment: If your CSS is static & the page is not scrollable, you can calc BB,BBoffsetX & BBoffsetY once at the head of the app and then do mouseX & mouseY in your findxy. Otherwise you'll have to do all these calculations in findxy.

Comment: hi there, i find that adding this code does make the offset work relative to the mouse location, but when i resize the page, lets say on a mobile iphone 1, then there is an offset again. Is there any way to fix this? thanks!

Comment: Yes, you must recalculate BB,BBoffsetX & BBoffsetY.

Comment: i see, is there any way to implement that in code to allow for browser resizing? thanks!

Comment: Yes, you could recalculate inside the `window.onresize` event handler. IMHO, unless this project is a once-in-a-lifetime adventure for you, you should read up on the basics of web programming--including learning the problems associated with hooking into the `window.onresizing` event.

Comment: yeah, i did just that by putting the code you mentioned above into a window.onresize event and calling resize, but it seems like doesnt integrate with the other events.

Comment: *Sigh*...Are you sure you've got your scoping right? You'll want to create the var BB, var BBoffsetX & var BBoffsetY globally at the head of your app. Then in resize you just **recalculate the existing vars**: `BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); BBoffsetX=BB.left; BBoffsetY=BB.top;`.